# add up all the values in a specific column matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to make a loop where it will check if the column sum is not equal to zero. If it is, I want to do something...

```
    for i:size(A,2)
        if A(:,sum(A)==0) ~=0
          %do something
        end
    end
```

but that sum returns all the columns in a matrix rather than going through one at a time

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your `if` with this:

```
if sum(A(:,i))~=0
```

which takes all the elements of the `i`-th column, adds them and compares them to `0`. If the sum is not zero the `%do something` will be executed.

What your `if` statement is doing is getting `A(:,sum(A)==0)`. Now `sum(A)==0` checks whether the sum of all the elements of `A` is zero. It probably wont be, in which case it will give a false (a zero), so you will be testing whether `A(:,0)~=0` which wont work because Matlab starts indexing at 1. If the matrix sum is 0, then `sum(A)==0` will be true (it will be 1) and you will get `A(:,1)~=0` which wont work because it will be comparing a vector `A(:,1)` to a scalar, `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve the same thing with this too:

```
for i = find(sum(A) ~= 0)
  % do something
end
```

This will iterate for every column `i` for which the column sum does not equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i = 1:size(A,2)
    if(sum(A(:,i)) ~= 0)
        % do something
    end
end
```